# exposing WCF- RIA Services to other client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odata, wcf-ria-services

I recently tried to follow this wonderful tutorial from Brian Noyes : ["this tutorial"](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-10-Exposing-Domain-Services-To-Other-Clients.aspx)

I got stuck consuming the odata endpoint. I could not find out for the life of me the Port number for the odata endpoint service.

Please advise what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It all depends on what oData service you are hitting, if you are hosting it, and how. Tutorials are usually run from Visual Studio, and when you run the RIA service in debug mode, depending on which VS version you have, it will be hosted in IIS Express, or the built-in VS host (Cassini), etc. Usually an icon sits in your tray and if you hover over it, it will show you which port the project is running on. If you are hitting a public service, you just need their endpoint, probably does not have a port (is port 80). If you are hosting in IIS, you choose your own port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with WCF-RIA, but the documentation states that by default DomainServices do not have a physical .SVC file generated for them at Design Time, but rather have a virtual .SVC, which represents the WCF Service associated with the domain. For a given DomainService the path to its .SVC can be determined using the following convention:

`[SilverlightApplicationBaseURI] + [DomainServiceFullName].svc`

At RunTime when the first request (within a particular Application Domain) is made for a DomainService's .SVC file , the registered httpModules intercept the call and RIA Services writes out an in memory .SVC file on the fly.

The following MSDN Blogs provide good information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2009/11/23/understanding-the-wcf-in-wcf-ria-services.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/11/22/ria-services-a-domainservice-is-a-wcf-service-add-service-reference.aspx